# Excluding Values with a Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a schema that utilizes three tables:

1. List of actors and INTERVAL actor_id
2. List of movie titles and INTERVAL movid_id
3. A table that catalogs the two such as the one below:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE actors_movies (
   actor_movie_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   actor_id INT,
   movie_id INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (actor_movie_id),
   KEY actor_id (actor_id),
   KEY movie_id (movie_id)
   );
   ```

I want to write a query that shows all movies an actor has NOT been in. The issue I am running into is that there can be multiple actors for one movie. So even if you exclude the actor based on the id or the name, that movie could still be pulled into the results.

I have tried to write the below query but it's a bit redundant and manual. How can I utilize a subquery to suppress movies an actor has been in and take into account the issue with multiple actors?

```
SELECT movie_name
FROM movies as m
JOIN actors_movies as am on m.movie_id = am.movie_id
JOIN actors as a on a.actor_id = am.actor_id
  WHERE actor_name <> 'actor_name'
   AND am.movie_id NOT IN(4,14);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case for a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
select movie_name
from movies as m
inner join actors_movies as am on m.movie_id = am.movie_id
left outer join actors as a on a.actor_id = am.actor_id
    and actor_name = 'actor_name'
where a.actor_id is null;
```

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for. Thank you!